# How can I use the return of a select into another select in order to sum them?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My problem is that I want to sum the column of quantity with their corresponding employee ID but it doesnt let me rename the result of the query with as

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT Orders.OrderID,Orders.EmployeeID,[Order Details].Quantity 
    FROM Orders  INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
    ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
    ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID
```

It doesnt let me put:

```
AS name (query)

or (query) AS name
```

In order for me to use another select query like this:

```
SELECT SUM([Orders Detail].Quantity) FROM queryResult Group By Orders.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   SELECT SUM(QUANTITY),EmployeeId FROM(
         SELECT ORD.OrderID,ORD.EmployeeID,OD.Quantity 
            FROM Orders AS ORD
            INNER JOIN DimEmployee  AS DE
            ON ORD.EmployeeID=DE.EmployeeID 
            INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS OD 
            ON OD.OrderID = ORD.OrderID 
            ) AS X
Group By EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should give you what you want.

```
    SELECT 
    Orders.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
    SUM([Order Details].Quantity) AS TotalQty
    FROM Orders 
    INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
      ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
        ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID 
    GROUP BY 
     Orders.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a straight forward aggregation, or a window function to return all details. **You may need to remove the `OrderID` from the `SELECT` list and `GROUP BY` if you don't want the results grouped at that level.**

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.EmployeeID,
    EmpTotal = SUM([Order Details].Quantity) 
FROM Orders  
    INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
    ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
    ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.EmployeeID


SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.EmployeeID,
    PartitionedTotal = SUM([Order Details].Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Orders.EmployeeID, Orders.OrderID) --here you may only want to partition by the EmployeeID instead of both
FROM Orders  
    INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
    ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
    ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID
```